# track/count unlock attemp made in pattern

Tags: android, unlock, lockscreen, login-attempts

I have developed a small application which can recognize when device get lock and unlock using 
`BroadcastReceiver`, plus `filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)` and `filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)`.

This work well and log properly when screen Lock & Unlock, but it is not giving me the attempt result of unlock, means I want to track each attempt and log that, if unlocking pattern is correct or not and log "Unlock Success" OR "Unlock Fail" at each attempt made to unlock device. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use Device Administration APIs of android do achieve this.

You need BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN permission to track that.